# Troubleshooting AWS Lambda's Climbing Memory Usage Between Invocations

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, memory-leaks

I have a AWS Lambda running on Java 11 where its main workload involves downloading a file from S3 bucket (about 500MB), parsing the file then load the data into a HashMap stored in the Lambda's memory for further processing.

The issue is that in between invocations of the same Lambda instance, the max memory usage of the Lambda keeps increasing even though I don't save the downloaded files' data into a static variable during each invocation.

From what I read here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/configurations.html

> Global variables and objects stored in the INIT phase of a Lambda invocation retain their state between warm invocations. They are completely reset only when the execution environment is run for the first time (also known as a “cold start”). Any variables stored in the handler are destroyed when the handler exits. It’s best practice to use the INIT phase to set up database connections, load libraries, create caches, and load immutable assets.

> When you use third-party libraries across multiple invocations in the same execution environment, be sure to check their documentation for usage in a serverless compute environment. Some database connection and logging libraries may save intermediate invocation results and other data. This causes the memory usage of these libraries to grow with subsequent warm invocations. In cases where memory grows rapidly, you may find the Lambda function runs out of memory, even if your custom code is disposing of variables correctly.

I cannot find any documentation on the third-party libraries on how the functions store variables in a serverless environment and that makes it very difficult for me to debug the possible memory leak issue on the AWS Lambda in **between invocations**.

What should I do to debug the variables/objects causing the memory leak?

Comment: For Java, any instance variables of the handler class are also retained between invocations.

Comment: that is a surprise to me, then how should I get the JVM to recycle the instance variables of the handler class before the next invocation?

Comment: This may not be a memory leak at all, depending on you JVM settings and what GC mechanism you are using. The JVM may not free the memory until it needs to, so you may see increasing memory usage without having a memory leak. Without further metrics it is really hard to say for sure. This article is a good starting point: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-monitoring-the-java-virtual-machine-garbage-collection-on-aws-lambda/

Comment: An `init()` method that you call at the top of the handler is probably the easiest. But since you don't post any code, or describe how the resources are used during Lambda execution, we can't be sure.